# get data from service in custom UITable View in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3auPa.png) .Im new to IOS. I am making an app where I want to get data from there in `UITableView`.
I have seen many blogs and post related to getting data in custom style, but I don't get my answer. I want to show an image in `UIImageView` and some labels values in label from service. Im using built in service to get data.
There are many post related to static data loading on custom. Can anyone guide how can I load data in my own custom style UItable VIEW FROM SERVICE?

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried so far  to make your point clear.

Comment: i have followed a blog http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/Services/WebServices-Page6.htm , but I'm not getting how can i do this for custom style. @SushilSharma

Comment: So, basically you want to fetch data from your server and populate that data to your tableView. Is it ?

Comment: I recommend you to follow one of the many tutorials available, i.e., this one https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/791/uitableview/3916/uitableview-delegate-and-datasource#t=201705231114162101422

Comment: yes but in custom style with having name label,pricelabel,locationlabel and an image in image view. @SushilSharma

Comment: What does "in custom style" mean ? a custom tableViewCell ? You need to elaborate your question by adding the amount of code you tried.

Comment: the link of blog i have said is the way i followed, my data is coming from service but in style Title and Subtitle way. I want to show like on right side i have image view in which image should appear and beside image view there must be name label,pricelabeland location label where there values from service appear. @SushilSharma

Comment: i have seen al of these examples but got no answer. @JavierQuevedo

Comment: What about posting a screenshot ? 
From what I have understood about your problem, I suggest this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/ .
I hope it can help you.

Comment: i have added screenshot  like that i want . @SushilSharma

Comment: i have seen ur link before but they r taking static array data , i want to load from service , I'm not getting the way i should do that. Can u help me please? @SushilSharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat I can understand your question.My answer is here

FindHomeViewController.m

```
#import "FindHomeViewController.h"
#import "DataTableViewController.h"

@interface FindHomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation FindHomeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)Search:(id)sender {  
   //Getting response from server
   NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                             @"country": @"UAE",
                             @"city": @"Dubai",
                             @"propertytype": @"Office",
                             @"propertystatus": @"Av‌​ailable",
                             @"propertyarea" : @"Kanal",
                             @"minprice" : @"800",
                             @"maxprice" : @"900"
                             };

    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:0 error:nil];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.pk.house/app_webservices/get_properties.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *dataTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest: request
                                                             fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                              if(data != nil)
                                                              {
                                                               NSError *parseError = nil;
                                                               //If the response is in dictionary format
                                                              NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
                                                               NSArray *arr=[dictionary valueForKey:@"property_data"];
                                                             NSLog(@"arr:%@",arr);

                                                             //Updating UIMain Thread
                                                             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                               UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                                                               DataTableViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DataTableViewController"];
                                                               vc.arrResprev = [arr mutableCopy];
                                                               [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

                                                               });

                                                             }
                                                             else
                                                                    NSLog(@"Data returned the parameter is nil here");
                                                         }];
                                                         [dataTask resume];
}
```

See my Custom Cell Image View

[image]

CustomeCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell


@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *priceLabel;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *locationLabel;

@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgvwRes;



@end
```

CustomCell.m

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

DataTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DataTableViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tvCustomers;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *listOfCustomers;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrResprev;



@end
```

DataTableViewController.m

```
#import "DataTableViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"


@interface DataTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation DataTableViewController


@synthesize tvCustomers,arrResprev,listOfCustomers;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    listOfCustomers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    listOfCustomers = arrResprev;
    [tvCustomers reloadData];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return listOfCustomers.count;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 134;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tvCustomers dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = nib[0];
    }
    cell.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[listOfCustomers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"dealer_name"]];
    cell.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[listOfCustomers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"price"]];
    cell.locationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[listOfCustomers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"location"]];
    NSString *strImgURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[listOfCustomers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"images"]];
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strImgURL];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Data has loaded successfully.");
    }
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    cell.imgvwRes.image = omg;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I'm using storyboard not nib, can u edit it for storyboard?Than i can test.  @user3182143

Comment: I used above my code in storyboard only please check it.

Comment: sorry, okay let me try. @user3182143

Comment: instead of nib i have used uiview controller in which i use uitableview. @user3182143

Comment: create separate cstom UItable View cell with .h,.m, .xib.

Comment: i have tried it , it is not displaying anything. Now what should i do? @user3182143

Comment: there is no any response in console. @user3182143

Comment: Give me your URL

Comment: my url? @user3182143

Comment: the url is right and its working right when i follow the blog .my data comes in table view when i follow this bloghttp://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/Services/WebServices-Page6.htm .@user3182143

Comment: is ur response coming? @user3182143

Comment: plzz help me im stuck to this issue from a week. @user3182143

Comment: No I tried your given url  but the response is not coming.

Comment: I think you are using local url.Others can't run.

Comment: there is nothing showing me in console. @user3182143

Comment: its  not a local url its connected to a site and getting data. @user3182143

Comment: any other solution for this. @user3192143

Comment: Send me your project

Comment: ur email id. @user3182143

Comment: Tell me your mail id.I will send the test mail.

Comment: I sent you the text mail.Now you can send it to me.

Comment: Have you got mail?

Comment: yup. I'm here @user3182143

Comment: I run your application now

Comment: on image . @user318143

Comment: Which view controller?

Comment: country=%@&city=%@&propertytype=%@&propertystatus=%@&propertyarea=%@&minprice=%@&maxprice=%@

Comment: Tell me the input parameters for above

Comment: NSString *parameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"country=%@&city=%@&propertytype=%@&propertystatus=%@&propertyarea=%@&minprice=%@&maxprice=%@",_but1.titleLabel.text,_but2.titleLabel.text,_but3.titleLabel.text,@"",@"",@"",@""]; . @user3182143

Comment: FindHomeViewController . @user3182143

Comment: anything happen? @user3182143

Comment: Response is zero

Comment: We have to give all input parameters without empty

Comment: The parameteres are - country=UAE&city=Dubai&propertytype=Plot&propertystatus= &propertyarea= &minprice= &maxprice=

Comment: What about propertystatus,propertyarea,min and max price

Comment: Send me missing parameters value immediately

Comment: NSString *parameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"country=%@&city=%@&propertytype=%@&propertystatus=%@&propertyarea=%@&minprice=%@&maxprice=%@",_but1.titleLabel.text,_but2.titleLabel.text,_but3.titleLabel.text,_but4.titleLabel.text,_but5.titleLabel.text,_minPrice.text,_maxPrice.text];
    
try with this. @user3182143

Comment: have u got this? @user3182143

Comment: What can I give property status,property area,max and min price in that field?

Comment: Tell me the property status,property area,min & max price values.

Comment: anything  u can , there is no filter now , when u fill all the form and hit search button it will show all the data from url. @user3182143

Comment: there is no specific values in them u can add any value in them. @user3182143

Comment: The parameteres are - country=UAE&city=Dubai&propertytype=Office&propertystatus=Available&propertyarea=Kanal&minprice=800&maxprice=900

Comment: response is nil or 0

Comment: I got the output

Comment: Success success

Comment: I got the response now.

Comment: let me check. @user3182143

Comment: I will send your project to your mail id.

Comment: mail me this project . @user3182143

Comment: i haven't  got any mail . @user3182143

Comment: I will send you

Comment: please send me the project , i have to test it . @user3182143

Comment: bro im waiting for the mail. @user3182143

Comment: I sent it to you.Please check it.

Comment: I fetch all data in array.Now you need to show in table view that.That is also in above answer.Please look the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: bro i have no idea how to show that data in table view , i need ur help . @user3182143

Comment: bro please help me seriously? @user3182143

Comment: See cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: I have tried the code but it is not showing anything just this is coming in console In main thread--completion handler. @user3182143

Comment: Tomorrow I can help you.Now I can't.Wait.

Comment: bro I'm waiting for u . @user3182143

Comment: bro please help u said i'll help today. @user3182143

Comment: seriously i need ur help . @user3182143

Comment: When I click search button in Find Home View Controller which table view do you load?

Comment: According to project my DataTableViewController this table view open . @user3182143

Comment: have u got that? @user3182143

Comment: Once I click search button immediately shows the table view.I can't find out where you call that line in your code.

Comment: the project that i had sent u was according to the blog to whom i had given reference , now u have added ur code in Find Home View Controller , i think u know where we have to call it. @user3182143

Comment: it move to table view through segue .

Comment: Where do you use segue? From which view controller do you use segue?

Comment: from Find Home vc search button to DataTableViewController . @user3182143

Comment: have u got that? @user3182143

Comment: plzz help me in this plzz . @user3182143

Comment: im waiting for u . @user3182143

Comment: Name,Price,Location are enough in table view cell.You don't want imageView in table view cell?

Comment: i want an image view also , Image has to come from url, its compalsory. @user3182143

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to follow both [Appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/) and [mikesknowledgebase](http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/Services/WebServices-Page6.htm) tutorials .

One shows how to customize `UITableViewCell` and other shows how to populate `UITableView` with data fetched from server. You will have to do it in steps.

First, design the Custom `UITableViewCell`.

Then, follow Mike's tutorial to learn how to set data on cell from API call.

You will use `NSURLSession` to make API calls.
Follow [Link](http://hayageek.com/ios-nsurlsession-example/) to learn how to make an API  call.

Go through these links.

We can only help you in debugging where little amount of code will work. But cannot post code for the complete functionality.

Hope these links will help you.